# Drop Down Menu when hovered over opens multiple selections unintended

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I created a code for a drop down menu but when ever I hover over the drop down menu it will open all and not just the one hovered.

Heres my html:

```
<div class='menuTitle'>
   Medical
   <div class='menuContent'>
      Test<br />
      Test2<br />
      Test<br />
    </div>
</div>

<div class='menuTitle'>|</div>    

<div class='menuTitle'>
   Bro
   <div class="menuContent">
      test<br />
      comone<br />
   </div>
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
.menuTitle {
   display: inline-block;
}

.menuContent {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100px;
   background-color: gray;
   display: none;
   text-align:center;

}
```

Comment: Fiddle please . No Idea where the menu is http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You say the troubles start when you hover. Therefore, the problem must be in the hovering routines and/or the hovering CSS. However, you aren't showing us any of these!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div class="dropDown">
  <ul>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test-Dropdown
        <ul>
            <li>Drop down content</li>
            <li>Drop down content</li>
            <li>Drop down content</li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS: To active the dropdown do something like this.

```
.dropDown > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
.dropDown > ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

add anymore styles you would like it to have

[My fiddle to help you get started](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/XvQRH/)

Comment: thank you for taking the time to help out! but when i put the code in it appeared jumbled in list form on the site

Comment: Yeah I didn't give you all of the code you needed mate, just to get the ball rolling. I will give you some tips though, `list-style-type: none;` removes the default styles of an order/unorder list. You should also do `padding: 0;` and `margin: 0;`. If you need them to be an inline element then do this: on the `li` `float: left;` Refer to the jsfiddle for a complete nav using CSS3 and `ul/li`

Comment: I made a jsfiddle to show you the basic fundamentals, this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Are your links test, test2 and test? If so you have to put them in seperate divs, better still use ul and li for navigation. You can also use a generator for this http://cssmenumaker.com/

Comment: Hey thank you for the feedback, I tried both seperating them with divs and aswell as ul and li. For some reason it still does the same thing. I would use the menu maker but everytime i place it where i have my menu it messes everything up

Answer (score 0):

Here is a drop down menu, no javascript needed.

css

```
menu, menu ul.drop-menu {
padding:0;
margin: 0;}
menu li, menu ul.drop-menu li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;}
menu li a, menu li ul.drop-menu li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
background-color:#000 ;
padding: 5px;
display:inline-block;}
menu li {
position: relative;}
/*drop menu*/
menu li ul.drop-menu {
display:none;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
left: 0;
width: 100px;}
menu li:hover ul.drop-menu {
display:block;}
```

html

```
<ul id="menu">
<li>
    <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul class="drop-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Drop Menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Drop Menu 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Drop Menu 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Drop Menu 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</li>   
<li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    <ul class="drop-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Drop Menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Drop Menu 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Drop Menu 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Drop Menu 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
</li>
</ul>
```